# Call function after websql transaction finishes?

Tags: javascript, web-sql

How do I run a function when a specific web sql transaction has finished, so that the transaction commits before the function call?

Comment: When you create a transaction, you can specify a "success callback", which gets called after the transaction is over. Put your function call there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/#asynchronous-database-api):

A transaction is created using the database's `transaction(callback, errorCallback, successCallback)` method. Once all the queries created inside `callback` are completed, the transaction is committed and `successCallback` is invoked.

So you need to either pass your function as `successCallback`, or call it from inside whatever  `successCallback` you are using at the moment.

Comment: It can be worth noting that it's not really that clear when `errorCallback` is called, vs when `successCallback`. For example, not being able to reach the server might result in a call to `successCallback`.

Comment: `errorCallback` is called in response to any error in the transaction `callback` method, but this method **cannot be paused** while you wait for an AJAX response. if your `callback` function finishes without errors, naturally the transaction will be treated as successful and committed.